# How to clean memory working set via a command

Tags: memory, powershell, cmd.exe, memory-management

Memory management GUI applications like `TaskExplorer` and `RAMMap` offer the possibilty to clean memory's "Working set".

Is there a command line utility or a Powershell script or similar that can achieve this ?

Comment: These are 3rdP tools. not MS tools. What did your web search turn up? Remember those tools have lots of underlying code the produces what you are seeing. PowerShell or any other language, will not directly reproduce this. So, you'd have to code anything you need that is not direct, just as those tool developers had to. PowerShell does many things out of the box, but not everything you think of or what something else would provide, not without extra work, and potentially add-on stuff via .Net, etc. There should be no expectations that PS would mimic 3rdP tools.

Comment: I'm unclear on what "cleaning" working set would entail. its difficult for an external program to perform garbage collection, since to do that you need to know the start address and length of the objects on the heap, and be able to navigate to any objects composed therein. that's why GC is usually implemented in the runtime.

Comment: You can force garbage collection as well in your code by adding this as the final lines. [System.GC]::Collect();
[GC]::Collect();
[GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers(); --- of course if you loaded custoemr variables, COM objects, etc., you shoudl have clean-up code for those as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think this answer could be useful for you. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150528/is-there-any-open-source-software-like-rammap)

> There is an open-source tool here https://github.com/CodeDead/MemPlus

Also this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841845/clear-the-windows-7-standby-memory-programmatically/20585554#20585554) is useful.

They proposed a C# code as following:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace FreeMemory
{
//Declaration of structures
//SYSTEM_CACHE_INFORMATION
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
struct SYSTEM_CACHE_INFORMATION
{
    public uint CurrentSize;
    public uint PeakSize;
    public uint PageFaultCount;
    public uint MinimumWorkingSet;
    public uint MaximumWorkingSet;
    public uint Unused1;
    public uint Unused2;
    public uint Unused3;
    public uint Unused4;
}

//SYSTEM_CACHE_INFORMATION_64_BIT
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
struct SYSTEM_CACHE_INFORMATION_64_BIT
{
    public long CurrentSize;
    public long PeakSize;
    public long PageFaultCount;
    public long MinimumWorkingSet;
    public long MaximumWorkingSet;
    public long Unused1;
    public long Unused2;
    public long Unused3;
    public long Unused4;
}

//TokPriv1Luid
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
internal struct TokPriv1Luid
{
    public int Count;
    public long Luid;
    public int Attr;
}
public class Program
{
    //Declaration of constants
    const int SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED = 2;
    const string SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME = "SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege";
    const string SE_PROFILE_SINGLE_PROCESS_NAME = "SeProfileSingleProcessPrivilege";
    const int SystemFileCacheInformation = 0x0015;
    const int SystemMemoryListInformation = 0x0050;
    const int MemoryPurgeStandbyList = 4;
    const int MemoryEmptyWorkingSets = 2;

    //Import of DLL's (API) and the necessary functions 
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool LookupPrivilegeValue(string host, string name, ref long pluid);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool AdjustTokenPrivileges(IntPtr htok, bool disall, ref TokPriv1Luid newst, int len, IntPtr prev, IntPtr relen);

    [DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
    public static extern UInt32 NtSetSystemInformation(int InfoClass, IntPtr Info, int Length);

    [DllImport("psapi.dll")]
    static extern int EmptyWorkingSet(IntPtr hwProc);

    //Function to clear working set of all processes
    public static void EmptyWorkingSetFunction()
    {
        //Declaration of variables
        string ProcessName = string.Empty;
        Process[] allProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();
        List<string> successProcesses = new List<string>();
        List<string> failProcesses = new List<string>();

        //Cycle through all processes
        for (int i = 0; i < allProcesses.Length; i++)
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            p = allProcesses[i];
            //Try to empty the working set of the process, if succesfull add to successProcesses, if failed add to failProcesses with error message
            try
            {
                ProcessName = p.ProcessName;
                EmptyWorkingSet(p.Handle);
                successProcesses.Add(ProcessName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                failProcesses.Add(ProcessName + ": " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        //Print the lists with successful and failed processes
        Console.WriteLine("SUCCESSFULLY CLEARED PROCESSES: " + successProcesses.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
        for (int i = 0; i < successProcesses.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(successProcesses[i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("FAILED CLEARED PROCESSES: " + failProcesses.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
        for (int i = 0; i < failProcesses.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(failProcesses[i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    //Function to check if OS is 64-bit or not, returns boolean
    public static bool Is64BitMode()
    {
        return Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr)) == 8;
    }

    //Function used to clear file system cache, returns boolean
    public static void ClearFileSystemCache(bool ClearStandbyCache)
    {
        try
        {
            //Check if privilege can be increased
            if (SetIncreasePrivilege(SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME))
            {
                uint num1;
                int SystemInfoLength;
                GCHandle gcHandle;
                //First check which version is running, then fill structure with cache information. Throw error is cache information cannot be read.
                if (!Is64BitMode())
                {
                    SYSTEM_CACHE_INFORMATION cacheInformation = new SYSTEM_CACHE_INFORMATION();
                    cacheInformation.MinimumWorkingSet = uint.MaxValue;
                    cacheInformation.MaximumWorkingSet = uint.MaxValue;
                    SystemInfoLength = Marshal.SizeOf(cacheInformation);
                    gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(cacheInformation, GCHandleType.Pinned);
                    num1 = NtSetSystemInformation(SystemFileCacheInformation, gcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), SystemInfoLength);
                    gcHandle.Free();
                }
                else
                {
                    SYSTEM_CACHE_INFORMATION_64_BIT information64Bit = new SYSTEM_CACHE_INFORMATION_64_BIT();
                    information64Bit.MinimumWorkingSet = -1L;
                    information64Bit.MaximumWorkingSet = -1L;
                    SystemInfoLength = Marshal.SizeOf(information64Bit);
                    gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(information64Bit, GCHandleType.Pinned);
                    num1 = NtSetSystemInformation(SystemFileCacheInformation, gcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), SystemInfoLength);
                    gcHandle.Free();
                }
                if (num1 != 0)
                    throw new Exception("NtSetSystemInformation(SYSTEMCACHEINFORMATION) error: ", new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
            }

            //If passes paramater is 'true' and the privilege can be increased, then clear standby lists through MemoryPurgeStandbyList
            if (ClearStandbyCache && SetIncreasePrivilege(SE_PROFILE_SINGLE_PROCESS_NAME))
            {
                int SystemInfoLength = Marshal.SizeOf(MemoryPurgeStandbyList);
                GCHandle gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(MemoryPurgeStandbyList, GCHandleType.Pinned);
                uint num2 = NtSetSystemInformation(SystemMemoryListInformation, gcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), SystemInfoLength);
                gcHandle.Free();
                if (num2 != 0)
                    throw new Exception("NtSetSystemInformation(SYSTEMMEMORYLISTINFORMATION) error: ", new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    //Function to increase Privilege, returns boolean
    private static bool SetIncreasePrivilege(string privilegeName)
    {
        using (WindowsIdentity current = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(TokenAccessLevels.Query | TokenAccessLevels.AdjustPrivileges))
        {
            TokPriv1Luid newst;
            newst.Count = 1;
            newst.Luid = 0L;
            newst.Attr = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

            //Retrieves the LUID used on a specified system to locally represent the specified privilege name
            if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(null, privilegeName, ref newst.Luid))
                throw new Exception("Error in LookupPrivilegeValue: ", new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));

            //Enables or disables privileges in a specified access token
            int num = AdjustTokenPrivileges(current.Token, false, ref newst, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero) ? 1 : 0;
            if (num == 0)
                throw new Exception("Error in AdjustTokenPrivileges: ", new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
            return num != 0;
        }
    }

    //MAIN Program
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Clear working set of all processes
        EmptyWorkingSetFunction();

        //Clear file system cache
        ClearFileSystemCache(true);

        //Waiting for input of user to close program
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please do not post only links as an answer as the linked content might change or get removed, rendering your answer useless. Instead quote the important parts and then provide the link as reference only.

Comment: @DarkDiamond thank you for your comment. I have added sth to the answer